# How to replace every nth occurrence of pattern using sed ONLY

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have searched all over the web but i can't find any good solutions. I have read on many forums that `sed` is not the tool (but `awk` is) for this but it makes no sense to me why. I mean you can do a simple substitution for occurrence number 5 for example like: `sed 's/pattern/replace/5'` to replace only the 5th instance. Why can't `sed` do `'s/pattern/replace/<every 5th occur>'` for one line? Isn't that a basic function..

Anyway my problem is that our client's software runs on a windows environment that has limited linux functions and unfortunately `awk` is not available on the system. Installing new commands is NOT an option for the company for whatever reason.

So my question is, what is the best way to use `sed` and/or mixed with bash for replacing every nth occurrence of a pattern per line? I only have one line anyway as i already stripped all the new line characters. Is bash `for` loop the only way?

Comment: `awk` is now available in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which is Ubuntu at heart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't that a basic function..

Obviously, it isn't. But it's still *possible*:

```
sed 's/a\([^a]*\($\|a[^a]*\($\|a[^a]*\($\|a[^a]*\($\|a\)\)\)\)\)/A\1/g'
```

More readable with `-r` where we can drop the backslashes:

```
sed -r 's/a([^a]*($|a[^a]*($|a[^a]*($|a[^a]*($|a)))))/A\1/g'
```

i.e. `a`, followed by any number of non-`a`, followed by either end of line, or another `a`, followed by any number of non-`a`, etc. Everything after the first `a` is remembered in `\1`.

BTW, if Perl is available, you can use:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { @A = qw(a A) } s/a/$A[not $i++ % 5]/g'
```

`%` is the modulo operator. $i is incremented with each match, negation of the modulo is 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, etc., which used as the index into @A picks the correct `a` or `A`.

Comment: wow amazing!!!! yeah we have perl, i prolly use perl coz it's more readable!! thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: i'm trying to pass a bash variable instead of a hard coded 5. is it possible?

Comment: oh got it to work perl -pe 'BEGIN { @A = qw(a A) } s/a/$A[not ++$i %'"$myvar"']/g'

Comment: or you can pass a parameter: `perl -pe 'BEGIN { @A = qw(a A); $m = shift } s/a/$A[not $i++ % $m]/g' 5`

Comment: sorry last question!! instead of replace with "A" im trying to replace with a new line \n but it literally prints \n :-S

Comment: `qw` can't contain a newline. Initialize the array with a list instead: `@A = ( "a", "\n" )`

Comment: thank you soooooooo much!!!!! really happy you helped me out and i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Simple `sed` and a brace expansion:

```
sed '-es/pattern/replace/'{max..min..step} infile
```

replace **max** with a number >=number of occurrences of *pattern*, if you don't know that, set it as a largest number of characters in a longest line in your file.

---

```
$ sed '-es/a/A/'{20..1..5} <<<"aaaa aaaa   a a a aa a a a aa aa"
aaaa Aaaa   a A a aa a A a aa aA
```

To replace first occurrence too, use below:

```
$ sed '-es/a/A/'{{20..1..5},1} <<<"aaaa aaaa   a a a aa a a a aa aa"
Aaaa Aaaa   a A a aa a A a aa aA
```

Comment: thank you! i chose the solution without needing to specify the max amount but i really appreciate your time and helping me out!